# What does ecclesiastes mean?

Tags: meaning, etymology

I try to understand the word "ecclesiastes".

What does it mean, besides being the name a book in the Bible?

What are its root(s), prefix, or suffix?

What is its etymology?

Thanks and sorry in advance for not being able to access the important part of the Internet.

Comment: https://www.etymonline.com/word/ecclesiastes

Comment: I must have forgot `-s`.

Answer (score 2):

It is from  the Greek word that gave us "ecclesiastic", to render Hebrew qoheleth "one who addresses an assembly," (see etymonline or Wikipedia)

Ecclesiastic means "relating to priests and preachers", and this book is framed as a words of Solomon acting as preacher and describing and considering the actions and events of his reign.